# Where did the 'pwnage' or 'pwn' or (verb) 'to pwn' come from ?

Tags: terminology

I know it is a malformation of ownage or to dominate your opponent beyond normal or average means of victory, but why is it Pwnage?  Why the 'P' there?   Was it a combination of two different words?

Comment: p is right beside o and people do not check their spelling.

Comment: That's it ?? And it just stuck ?

Comment: Yes that's it. People laughed and thought it was funny and then it just spread.

Comment: ....  And I thought there was something interesting to the story -_-;

Comment: I heard it came from an Unreal map but I need to find the reference

Comment: @OrigamiRobot but why comment and no answer :( I'd so upvote you.

Comment: It's like the "blah blah blah !!!!1!!!!!!" thing, the implication there being a person who is both overexcited and too stupid to hold down the shift key properly.

Comment: I seem to remember seeing somewhere that there was a very old video or arcade game that displayed the message "You have been pwned" when you lost, which was presumably a typo of "owned" as everyone else is saying, but it eventually turned into a meme like "All your base are belong to us".  I know I had seen a screenshot of it, but I can't seem to find it anymore.

Comment: @AlanB They may not be stupid--they might have a condition where their fingers twitch :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best place to look is here, http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/owned-pwned

> Owned (below: Variations) is a “leetspeak” slang word, derived from
>   the traditional meaning of the verb “own”, as meaning to appropriate
>   or conquer to gain ownership. The term strongly implies domination,
>   severe defeat, and/or humiliation of a rival. For instance, “I owned
>   the network at MIT” indicates that the speaker had cracked the servers
>   and had the same root-level privileges that the legitimate owner of
>   the servers had. It is also now primarily used in the Internet gaming
>   culture to taunt an opponent who has just been soundly defeated (e.g.,
>   “You just got pwned!”) and as popular slang, outside of the internet.
>   It is partly synonymous with a high degree of fail, and while
>   sometimes these terms have been used interchangeably, it is more
>   proper to say that someone or something is “fail” if they have been
>   “owned.”

Edit as per comments.

> **"P"wned**
>   The “p” in “pwned” alteration within the computer community
>   has been believed to have have originated from typing too fast on the
>   standard English QWERTY keyboard, thus missing the “o” and typing “p”
>   instead. It could also be thought to pay homage to early hackers who
>   tampered with phone equipment rather than computers--and “pwn” may
>   simply be following this trend. (e.g., phishing, phreaking) According
>   to one definition in the UrbanDictionary, the term “pwn” dates back to
>   the 1960s at M.I.T. It was used competitively by programmers working
>   on chess AI. When one out programmed the others he would refer to
>   himself as King and the others as pawns. It started being used on Fido
>   Net across the BBS world before internet went public, although it was
>   used on the internet between university’s at the time.

Comment: Would be useful if you'll also quote the reason for the "p" variation, since that's what the question is actually asking.

Comment: Unless a quote supports that pwn was in fact a typo I always believed it was adopted to signify the next level of ownage, since p is one letter after o in the alphabet. I may be wrong but it makes sense, and over time the popularity of pwn increased and it's "own + 1" meaning flattened out to the same severity of ownage.

Answer (score 1):

The origin of the word is exactly what DavidYell said.

He omitted the reason "p" is used, though, so here comes:
Using "P" instead of "o" has a simple reason; it comes from a common typo, when writing "owned" in a hurry. When you're pwning your opponents, you mostly don't have time to correct your typos. That also is why it should be pronounced the same way.

Answer (score -1):

pwned appeared in text on a video game screen when the gamer lost.

you have been pwned.

the typo appeared for all to see. and that is how it spread.  not through normal typos, but that it was a typo on a video game.

Comment: This sounds like the start of a great answer. But your missing quite a bit.. What game was it in? When was it released? Do you have any source that this is how it started and that it was a typo?

Answer (score -4):

**PWN**, or **PWNED** is derived from **OWN** respectively **OWNED**. 
Some people say the 'p' comes from the word 'pawn' (farmer, boor, chuff)..

But 'p' is actually standing for **POWER** -> ***POWERownd/POWERowned*** and thats then a even bigger 
*denudation* in sense of **owning** or **dominating** your opponents :-)

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but do you have a reliable source for this?

Comment: It's a backformation. The real origin is most likely the result of a common typo that eventually became 'standard' usage.